# How to ignore a Suite or a Test in ZIO Test?

Tags: scala, zio, zio-test

I could not find anything on how to ignore a Suite or a Test with ZIO Test.

Whether in an example nor in the documentation (https://zio.dev/docs/usecases/usecases_testing)

There is an `ignored` in the `test package object`:

```
  /**
   * Creates an ignored test result.
   */
  final val ignored: ZTest[Any, Nothing, Nothing] =
    ZIO.succeed(TestSuccess.Ignored)
```

But how can it be used in your code?

I tried different things, but with no success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to ignore a test is using `TestAspect.ignore`. For example:

```scala
test("A test that would otherwise fail") {
  assert(true, isFalse)
} @@ ignore
```